# How to retrieve video format using cvGetCaptureProperty

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, opencv

I am trying to retrieve the video format

Ex. my input video file is video.mpeg then I want format as mpeg

I used this function

```
double Format = cvGetCapturePrperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT);
```

but it returns 0.000

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT` is not what you think. Check the documentation.

You are probably looking for:

```
double val = cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC );
char* fourcc = (char*) (&val);
```

Comment: what does it return?? how to convert the value returned in double to char?

Comment: Updated answer, reload the page. Consider accepting my answer as the official problem solver by clicking in the checkbox near it: this helps future visitors.